# Laravel policy missing argument

Tags: php, laravel

В политике есть такой код:

```
   public function view(User $user, User $model): bool
    {
        return ($user->id == $model->id || in_array('read_users', $user->access));
    }
```

Первая модель - авторизированный пользователь, а вторая модель - просматриваемый пользователь. Ничего не работает, тк вторая модель не приходит в политику.

Запускается все в роутинге:

```
 Route::get('/{id}', [UserController::class, 'show'])->name('users.show')->middleware('can:view,' . User::class);
```

Model binding НЕ используется в контроллере, тк логика работы с бд вынесена в репозитории.

Comment: Я не эксперт в ларке, но если бы мне в метод пришли 2 аргумента одного класса, я бы тоже не смог определить куда что подставлять

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас есть логическая ошибка. Вы в мидлваре передаете название класса, а в политике проверяете с объектом. Если посмотреть документацию, то Model::class передается в методах политики где не требуется проверка объекта.

Т.е. если не брать мидлвар, а проверять в контроллере, то разница такая:

```
//  Передаете объект, так как требуется проверка объекта
if ($user->can('update', $post)) {
    //
}
// передаете название класса, так как объект не нужен при проверке
if ($user->can('create', Post::class)) {
    // Executes the "create" method on the relevant policy...
}
```

В вашей логике, вам нужен в политике объект. Т.е если вашу проверку перенести в контроллер, то будет примерно так:

```
if($user->can('view', $model)){
}
```

А что вы передаете в мидлвар? Не объект, а название класса.

Как перенести туда нужный объект? По простому никак, только если писать свой RBAC или делать обертку над дефолтным. Опять таки, в мидлвар вы все равно объект не передадите, но сможете в мидлваре достать параметры из реквеста и уже там создать модель для проверки.

Самый простой путь без костылей и наворотов - делать авторизацию в контроллере.

Comment: у меня задача стоит, не использовать ни в коем случае авторизацию в котроллере)) в контроллере сделать я итак могу)) я оттуда переделываю сейчас

Comment: плюс я написал, что в контроллер мне не приходит модель. То есть, чтобы провернуть авторизацию, мне нужно получить модель, а это уже нарушает логику, то есть получается контроллер исполнил свою функцию, а потом проверил и не отдал результат

Comment: @PaulWall Это не нераушает логику. Вы получаете модель из репозитория, а потом суете ее в проверку политики.  Плюс, сами прикиньте, вы в политике используете модель, но получать вы ее не хотите. Это как? Она из воздуха возьмется? Если цель все сделать в мидлваре - я уже написал, пишите свой мидлвар.